# TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars (Image Classification)

Tags: python, numpy

```
import os
from skimage.io import imread
from skimage.transform import resize
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score, KFold
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, f1_score, precision_score, recall_score, confusion_matrix
from sklearn.tree import plot_tree
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


input_dir = '/content/drive/My Drive/DM_dataset/'

categories = ['battery', 'dc_volt_src', 'diode', 'gnd', 'inductor', 'resistor', 'voltmeter']

data = []
labels = []

for category_idx, category in enumerate(categories):
    for file in os.listdir(os.path.join(input_dir, category)):
        img_path = os.path.join(input_dir, category, file)
        img = imread(img_path)
        img = resize(img, (28, 28))
        img = img / 255.0
        data.append(img.flatten())
        labels.append(category_idx)

data = np.asarray(data, dtype="object")
labels = np.asarray(labels)

kf = KFold(n_splits=5, shuffle=True, random_state=42)

for train_index, test_index in kf.split(data):
    X_train, X_test = data[train_index], data[test_index]
    y_train, y_test = labels[train_index], labels[test_index]

k_values = [3, 5, 7]
distance_metrics = ['euclidean', 'manhattan']

for k in k_values:
    for metric in distance_metrics:
        knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=k, metric=metric)
        knn.fit(X_train, y_train)
        y_pred = knn.predict(X_test)

        accuracy = accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)
        f1 = f1_score(y_test, y_pred, average='weighted')
        precision = precision_score(y_test, y_pred, average='weighted')
        recall = recall_score(y_test, y_pred, average='weighted')

        print(f"KNN-{k} {metric.capitalize()}:")
        print(f"Accuracy: {accuracy:.2f}")
        print(f"F1-score: {f1:.2f}")
        print(f"Precision: {precision:.2f}")
        print(f"Recall: {recall:.2f}")
        print(confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred))
        print()
```

### Here's the error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-70-2e901eccd02c> in <cell line: 4>()
      5     for metric in distance_metrics:
      6         knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=k, metric=metric)
----> 7         knn.fit(X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0], -1), y_train)
      8         y_pred = knn.predict(X_test.reshape(X_test.shape[0], -1))
      9 

5 frames

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/_array_api.py in _asarray_with_order(array, dtype, order, copy, xp)
    183     if xp.__name__ in {"numpy", "numpy.array_api"}:
    184         # Use NumPy API to support order
--> 185         array = numpy.asarray(array, order=order, dtype=dtype)
    186         return xp.asarray(array, copy=copy)
    187     else:

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

I've tried to reshaping the array, but it didn't work.

Comment: Edit the error so it's readable.  Inclding more frames may help. My guess is `fit` is having problems making a numeric dtype array from either `xtrain` or `ytrain`